# Azure Storage service REST API for block Blobs : Content Length Issue

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use azure storage rest api to push block blob type but issue is about **Content Length** to be known before hand in order to upload.

Do we have a workaround for cases wherein inputStream need to be relayed without having this length info available.

```
String accesskey = "accesskey";
String storageAccount = "storageAccount";
String containerName = "containerName";
String workgroupId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String objectId = "1." + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String blobName = getAzureAccessKey(containerName, workgroupId, objectId);
String version = "2018-03-28";
String putData = "testData";

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String currentDate = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";

String urlResource = "/"+ Paths.get(storageAccount, containerName, blobName).toString();
String headerResource = "x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" + currentDate + "\nx-ms-version:" + version;
String putUrl = "https://" + storageAccount + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + containerName + "/" + blobName;
System.out.println(putUrl);
String newline = "\n";

List listToSign = Lists.newArrayList();
listToSign.add("PUT");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("application/octet-stream");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add("");
listToSign.add(headerResource);
listToSign.add(urlResource);

String stringToSign = String.join(newline, listToSign);
 Base64 base64 = new Base64();


System.out.println(stringToSign);
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(base64.decode(accesskey), "HmacSHA256"));
String authKey = new String(base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

String authHeader =  "SharedKey " + storageAccount + ":"+ authKey;

System.out.println(authHeader);

InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(putData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), -1,
        ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

// set chunked transfer encoding ie. no Content-length
entity.setChunked(true);
HttpPut httpPut = null;
try {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient =  new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.removeRequestInterceptorByClass(org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.class);

    httpPut = new HttpPut(putUrl);
    httpPut.setHeader("Host", storageAccount + ".blob.core.windows.net");
    httpPut.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
    //httpPut.setHeader("Content-Length","0");
    httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    httpPut.addHeader("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
    httpPut.addHeader("x-ms-date", currentDate);
    httpPut.addHeader("x-ms-version", version);
    httpPut.addHeader("Authorization",authHeader);


    httpPut.setEntity(entity);

    System.out.println("Request Headers");

    for (Header header : httpPut.getAllHeaders()) {
        System.out.println(header.getName() + ":" + header.getValue());
    }
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());


    for (Header header: response.getAllHeaders()) {
        System.out.println(header.getName()+":"+ header.getValue());
    }
    // Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.
    String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(content);

} finally {

    if(httpPut != null ){
        httpPut.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Response from server

```
HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.
```

Above code works if i set content length as part of signature and header info.

Comment: Above code works if i set content length as part of signature and header info

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. You will need to specify the content length. However I am curious to know your use case.

Comment: Why not use Azure Storage Java SDK instead of invoking REST API directly? https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java

Comment: Whole issue is about not having Content length and using azure api,ie not to stage user data before it can be streamed to api. We already use SDK but now requirement is to push input data stream directly to api.GCS storage api allows that hence was bit of a surprise by this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ByteArrayEntity` to get the content length instead of using `InputStreamEntity`

Here is a simple demo for your reference:

```
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null ;
        try {
            fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("D:/Test/Test.txt");
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] bytes=new byte[102400];
            int x=0;
            while ((x=fileInputStream.read(bytes))!= -1){
                bos.write(bytes,0,x);
            }
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity byteArrayEntity=new ByteArrayEntity(data);
            int contentLength=data.length;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As Zhaoxing Lu said above, we can use Java SDK to achieve this, here is the demo that use Java SDK for your reference:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobItem;

public class Main {

     public static final String ConnString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxxb;AccountKey=O7xxxx8e86XQSy2vkvSi/x/e9l9FhLqxxxxjkly1DsQPYY5dF2JrAVxxxxo29ZrrGJA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        uploadBlob("mycontainer","TechTalk.pptx","E:\\Test\\TechTalk.pptx");
        System.out.println("Success");

    }

    public static void uploadBlob(String containerName, String blobName,String filePath) {
        CloudStorageAccount account = null;
        CloudBlobContainer container = null;
        try {
            account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(ConnString);
            CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
            container = client.getContainerReference(containerName);
            container.createIfNotExists();
            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            FileInputStream fileinputStream=new FileInputStream(filePath);
            cloudBlockBlob.upload(fileinputStream, fileinputStream.available());
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

We can get Java SDK at: [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java)

Comment: Thanks lee for checking this out but our requirement is to use api without having content length info.Consider it as a proxy layer app to relay user data to api without staging data at app end.Also this stream will be manipulated on the fly hence even if user passes content length of data stream it wouldn't be useful